# Rounding numbers using the 4/5 rounding rule

Tags: c++, class, rounding, rounding-error

I'm currently learning C++.

> I have to write a simple `class Money` that performs calculations involving dollars and cents where arithmetic has to be accurate to the last cent using the 4/5 rounding rule.

I have never dealt before with monetary amounts so I'm having some troubles in understanding how to get the best from my class. I know that I shouldn't represent monetary amounts with `float`. So I use two data members for my class to store separately dollars and cents :

```
long int dollars
long int cents
```

My problem is that I don't know when and how I should round numbers. I asked myself this question while I was trying to implement an input operator for this class. Suppose the user enters as input the values : `12.456, 45.999, 9.54`.

1. When should I round these numbers ?
2. Should I first use them in arithmetic operations and then round the result or round them directly as they are entered into the program ?

Comment: Do not round currency. People are a bit picky about that. Just store in as groats (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groat_%28coin%29) - or cents in your case

Comment: Enlighten me or at least clarify; what exactly is the 4/5 rounding rule - just so we are all talking about the same thing.

Comment: If the assignment requires 4/5 rounding, then implement that. For real world currency, most countries have rules that require currency amounts be dealt with as fixed point decimal strings.

Comment: @Clifford - 4/5 rule. For positive decimal numbers, .4xxxxxx is rounded down, .5xxxxx is rounded up, so only the first digit after the decimal point is needed. For binary, it's .0xxxxxxx rounded down, .1xxxxxx rounded up.

Comment: Having separate dollar and cent members will just make the code more complex than necessary.  Just use cents, then overload the arithmetic operators and possibly << and >> for I/O.

Comment: @rcgldr : I'd call that *rounding to the nearest integer*, or *conventional rounding*, it was not that I did not know what he meant, but rather that the term is by no means universal, and that the question would benefit from clarification.

Comment: @Clifford - do a web search for 4/5 rounding, and you'll find a lot of hits. A common alternative used in physics and science is to round xxx.500000.... to the nearest even number (so that with uniform random numbers, there's a balance between rounding up and down).

Comment: @rcgldr : I did, and I didn't - though weirdly I searched again, and I do - typing error I imagine.  However you miss the point; the information should be in the question not have to be searched for.  You can assume programming expertise here perhaps, but not expertise of idioms and terminology that are domain or even culturally specific.

Comment: @Clifford I think your idea to use represent everything as cents is pretty good. I have been looking for a formula to convert a monetary amount to cents but haven't find anything. For example how can I store as a long int rpresenting cents the amount : 12.45002 ? How can I do that without losing data ?

Comment: @PieroBorrelli : Well you had that problem with your integer dollar + cent implementation, but your question talks about "calculations involving dollars and cents", and does not mention any requirement to store fractions of a cent.  The suggestion is an answer to a question you have not asked, which is why I posted it as a comment.  If you want to ask about it in detail, post a separate question, with clear requirements.

Comment: @Clifford I had problems with representing a number as the number of cents in a long int, after some researches I decided to use dollars and cents. But I would now like to just use cents....The problem statement says that arithmetic operations should be precise to the last cent using the 4/5 rounding rule. Just input and output need to be represented as dollars and cents.

Comment: @PieroBorrelli : Why should a user input more that two decimal places?  A solution is however is required for handling the result of percentage or division operations (for interest, tax or share allocation for example).

Comment: Note that if storing the full value in cents and you want to represent values greater than about 21 million dollars, you should use `long long`.  Even if storing dollars+cents, you'd need dollars in `long long` to allow values greater than about 4 billion dollars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having separate dollar and cent members will just make the code more complex than necessary.  Just use cents, then overload the arithmetic and assignment operators, constructor and possibly << and >> for I/O.

Addition and subtraction are trivial, just normal integer operations scaled by 100 in this case.  In general fixed-point division/multiplication requires re-scaling; you can ignore that in this case because dividing or multiplying money by money makes no sense; you may want to overload for money multiplied or divided by integers and floating-point types however (for tax, discount or  interest calculation for example).

By overloading << and >> operators for money, you can control how the cents value is input or presented - by converting it to/from `dollars.cents`.

There are a number of scenarios where rounding may be necessary, but in most cases these can be handled by operator overloading.  For example user input in dollars can be handled by the assignment operator and constructors, while interest, tax or share allocation calculations which may result in fractions of a cent may be handled by overloading the * and / operators (although probably internally using the assignment or constructor so that you only need the rounding in one place).

Holding the value in cents and rounding a floating point input or intermediate dollar value to the cent, with positive/negative value handling may be achieved as follows:

```
long long cents = static_cast<long long>((std::abs(dollars_fp) + 0.005) * 100) ;
if( dollars_fp < 0 )
{
    cents = -cents ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to perform operations on `cents` and use rounding only to print an amount to standard output.

You could use [locale](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/money_get/get/) facet to parse monetary expressions and [std::stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/), along with [stream manipulators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/library/manipulators/) to specify precision, as a base structures to implement the class you want.

Here is an example of conversion between cents and dollars:

```
int sum_in_cents = 10000;

// stringstream imbued with the local configuration
std::stringstream ss;
ss.imbue(std::locale(""));

// ss contains $100.00 (assuming a en_US locale configuration)
ss << std::showbase << std::put_money(sum_in_cents);
```

In addition, there is [a boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/locale/doc/html/formatting_and_parsing.html) for currency formatting.

---

Note: Conventional 4/5 rounding is performed by the standard library function [`round()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/). If you want to implement something yourself, you could do:

```
double round (double n) 
{
    return (n > 0.0) ? floor(n + 0.5) : ceil(n - 0.5);
}
```

if you want an integer result from the rounding, you don't need either `ceil()` or `floor()`:

```
int round (double i)
{
    return (i > 0.0) ? (i + 0.5) : (i - 0.5); 
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

1. The best I can say is to read the values in as a string. You can at this point manipulate every item/number since strings are essentially arrays of chars.
2. Another option would be to type cast e.g.

   float x = 10.01;   // x = 10.01

   (int) y = x;       // y = 10

read values in as floats and break them down from there.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend multiplying the input by 1000 or so to make the input into a whole number, that way operations you make on it are more accurate. After rounding you can use integer division to find the dollars and the remainder operator to get the cents (times 10). As for your second question, you should at least convert the number into whole numbers of dollars and cents before rounding, and then you may choose which you prefer. Here's an example of rounding the input:

```
/* Note: Code untested */
double x;
std::cin >> x;    // x = 45.999
long y = x * 1000;        // y = 45999

int dollars = y / 1000;    // dollars = 45
int cents = y % 1000       // cents = 999 (divide by 10 to get real # of cents)

if (cents % 10 >= 5) {   // if last digit should be rounded up (true)
    cents += 10;            // add 10 (cents = 1009)
    cents -= (cents % 10);   // remove the last digit (cents = 1000)
} 
else if (cents % 10 < 5) {  // if last digit should be rounded down (false)
    cents -= (cents % 10);   // remove last digit
}

cents /= 10;        // make cents a factor of 100 instead of 1000 (cents = 100)

if (cents >= 100) {    // if cents more than $1 (true)
    dollars++;       // adjust dollars (dollars = 46)
    cents -= 100;     // remove 100 from cents (cents = 0)
}

// prints "Amount is $46.0"
std::cout << "Amount is $" << dollars << "." << cents << "\n";
```

As for typecasts, they are not the best option for rounding. If you were to use the following code:

```
double x = 45.999;
int y = (int)x;
```

You would get `y == 45` because when casting any floating-point type to any integer-type, the fractional part is ignored altogether.

Hope this helps.